# How to split a zed-graph in three sections with a vertical line to separate them?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am having trouble splitting a zedgraph into sections, I want to be able to monitor my running sessions and thought I would try build a program that displays my results, mainly speed on a graph. The results are read from a text file, this is then stored currently in a int list and a pointparlist for the zedgraph. I want to be able to split the graph into three sections, the first 15% is the warm up part of the run, the middle (70%) is the main running session and finally the third is the cooling down session (15%). instead of plotting the whole session on a graph and manually trying to work out where my warm up ends ect I wanted to know if its possible to put a vertical line after the warm up and middle.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or help on this, I have been trying for a couple of days but I can not manage to put my intentions on a Google search if that makes sense.

Would it be a better approach to split the int list which stores the speed values before plotting it on the graph? I am open to advice on how to tackle this. Once again thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to draw two vertical lines, then it becomes 3 sections. Here's the code:

```
PointPairList warmUpList = new PointPairList();
    LineItem warmUpCurve = new LineItem("warmUpCurve");
    PointPairList coolingDownList = new PointPairList();
    LineItem coolingDownCurve = new LineItem("coolingDownCurve");

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an instance of Graph Pane
        GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

        // x & y variables to store the axis values
        double xVal;
        double yVal;

        // Clear the previous values if any
        warmUpList.Clear();
        coolingDownList.Clear();

        myPane.Legend.IsVisible = false;

        // Create a list using the above x & y values
        warmUpList.Add(myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min + myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep*1.5 , myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max);
        warmUpList.Add(myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min + myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep * 1.5, myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min);

        coolingDownList.Add(myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max - myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep * 1.5, myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max);
        coolingDownList.Add(myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max - myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep * 1.5, myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min);

        // Add the curves
        warmUpCurve = myPane.AddCurve(" ", warmUpList, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
        coolingDownCurve = myPane.AddCurve(" ", coolingDownList, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);

        TextObj WarmUpTextObj = new TextObj("Warm Up", myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min + myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep, myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max - myPane.YAxis.Scale.MajorStep);
        TextObj RunningTextObj = new TextObj("Running Test", myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max/2, myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max - myPane.YAxis.Scale.MajorStep);
        TextObj CoolingDownTextObj = new TextObj("Cooling Down", myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max - myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep, myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max - myPane.YAxis.Scale.MajorStep);

        myPane.GraphObjList.Add(WarmUpTextObj);
        myPane.GraphObjList.Add(RunningTextObj);
        myPane.GraphObjList.Add(CoolingDownTextObj);

        zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
    }
```

[image]